# static declaration behind dynamically declared arrays

Tags: c++, static, new-operator

I want to have an array in a function which retains its value when i exit the function i.e. for example-

```
 int func(int x)
 {
  static int arr[5];
 }
```

But the problem is that i don't know the size of the array beforehand (i.e. it depends on x).   So, i have to declare an array using 'new'.

Can it be done like this?

```
 static int *arr=new int[x];
```

or will i have to do:

```
  static int *static arr = new int[x]
```

If not then
how to do that?

Comment: Prefer using `static std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Use a `static std::vector<int>`.

Comment: This seems awkward because x may have different values on different calls.  What if x is 1 the first time it is called, and you allocate an array of 1 element, and then x is 2 the next time?

Answer (score 2):

`static int *arr = new int[x];` is OK. However, you need to worry about memory leak since there is not a good point for `delete [] arr;`.

As described in comments, a local `static std::vector<int> arr;` is preferred since its destructor is called automatically at the end of the program.

Comment: @timrau...if arr is not static then it will be destroyed once we exit the function...then how will we access the array elements?

Comment: @avinash No way. So you should find some way to let the caller access the address, such as `return arr;`, assign it to a `int**` parameter, or even assign it to a global `int*` (worst way, though).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think thats legal.
The reason you can use variables to "dynamically" size an array inside function scope is AFAIK because the array gets put on the stack:

```
void foo(int x)
{
   int bar[x]; // this is legal
} // but goes out-of-scope here :-(
```

Declaring the array `static` destroys this. Think of it this way: The linker has no chance of knowing the size of the array, hence cannot locate anything "beyond" the array (clearly not desirable).

So basically you need to use the heap via `new` and `delete`. Or better yet use `std::vector<>` as already suggested (uses heap internally).

Comment: The `int bar[x];` here is _illegal_ because `x` is not decided at compile time although GCC extension allows it.

Comment: Hmm, maybe its illegal in C++? It is allowed in C (C99).